# How to publish app to app store flutter on windows 10

Tags: ios, macos, flutter

I made an application using flutter, I own a windows 10 pc. I can't get a mac ( or a mac in cloud ), so is there a way to just build it and publish without having a mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build app for iOS you need Mac. Build tools for iOS apps exists only for macOS. You can try to use [Codemagic](https://codemagic.io) (it has a free plan) or a similar Cloud CI/CD service for build and publish your app to App Store.